# CellList: How to set row height dynamically?

Tags: gwt, gwt-celltable

I have a CellList which will have fix number cells in one page, i would like the cells extend to fill the whole CellList.

Suppose the CellList height is 100px, the cell number is 10, then one cell/row will be 10px, if the CellList height is 500px, each cell/row's height will be 50px.

The problem is, how to control the row height after table rendered, i tried to `addLoadingStateChangeHandler` on cell list and when `onLoad` i use GQuery to resize the cell height, but seems no effect.

Yes i can get each row's height beforehand, but how to apply to the CellList's CSS?

Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, when creating a new cell, specify its height(because we know the height beforehand), when resizing the CellList, just redraw it by specifying a new height.

Comment: you can also use conditional css and html 5 to solve this problem